# How to work with image Carousel jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating image carousel

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/KyleKatarn/ojxy3o0g/4/

and there are only two images in the carousel. now i've created a variable `var current = 1` and when the user clicks the `next` control button this variable gets `current++` . now i want `if (current > 2)` i want variable to be `current = 1` which is working just fine. but there is one problem i don't want my variable `current = 3`. because i'm working with just two images. i don't wana see the black background in my image carousel . i just want when it checks the second image, it scrolls back to the first image

My HTML

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://dogfeathers.com/3d/povray/images/3DGDDDDC.GIF" alt="image" id="a"></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.doschdesign.com/images2/Red-DH-VASLA-1.jpg" alt="image"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="slider-nav">
    <button data-dir="prev">Previous</button>
    <button data-dir="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

My JS

```
(function(){


var imgLength = $('img').length;
var current = 1;
var currentImage = $('img');

$('button').on('click',function(){

    if($(this).data('dir') === 'next')
    {
        current++;
        currentImage.animate({
            'left':'-=600px'
        });


        if(current > imgLength)
        {
            currentImage.animate({
                'left':'0px'
            });
            current = 1;

        }
    }

    if($(this).data('dir') === 'prev'){

        current--;
        currentImage.animate({
            'left':'+=600px'
        });
        if(current < 1)
        {
            currentImage.animate({
                'left': (600 * (1 - imgLength )) + 'px'
            });
            current = imgLength;
        }
    }

}); 


})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your default `animate` action after `if` statement or use `else`

```
var imgLength = $('img').length;
var current = 1;
var currentImage = $('img');

$('button').on('click',function(){

    if($(this).data('dir') === 'next'){
        current++;
        if(current > imgLength){
            currentImage.animate({
                'left':'0px'
            });

            // return here:
            return current = 1;
        }

        // move default action behind if statement (or use ELSE)
        currentImage.animate({
            'left':'-=600px'
        });
    // add ELSE here, so that the next IF statement isn't checked unnecessarily:
    }else if($(this).data('dir') === 'prev'){
        current--;
        if(current < 1){
            currentImage.animate({
                'left': (600 * (1 - imgLength )) + 'px'
            });
            // return here:
            return current = imgLength;
        }

        // move default action behind if statement (or use ELSE)
        currentImage.animate({
            'left':'+=600px'
        });
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ayqvpdwx/)